# Specific api has some middlewares in swagger api

Tags: laravel, swagger, openapi, swagger-php

I'm writing API documentation for my application using Swagger 3.0. My application has some apis that include some middlewares. I want to describe that which api has the middlewares (like `parameters` or `security` tag)

Is that possible in swagger or is there any trick to display that?

Comment: What do you mean by "API includes middleware"? Does this middleware affect the consumer-facing interface of your API (i.e. the requests that the clients are supposed to send and the responses received)?

Comment: @Helen, for example, I have a api `/api/room` and has a middleware `CheckApartment`, so the api `/api/room` includes middleware  `CheckApartmen`. For the 2nd question, yes, if the middleware `CheckApartment` is not passed, it returns response with 4xx code and error message.

Comment: Which middleware/framework do you use? Some frameworks use the standard [`operationId`](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/paths-and-operations/#operationid) to specify the controller/method name, others use custom `x-` extensions for that (e.g. `x-swagger-router-controller` or `x-openapi-router-controller`).

Comment: I'm using [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) framework and [DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger](https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger) for API swagger UI. I reference [this](https://swagger.io/specification/) to write api document